# How to Send a broadcast packet in a RDC layer in Contiki?

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to code my own RDC layer in contiki, with the PW-MAC protocol.
I was wondering how to send a broadcast in this layer because there will have no network and no transport layer.
The function i have to use will be:

```
NETSTACK_RDC.send(mac_callback_t sent, void *ptr)
```

But I really don't know what mac_callback_t and ptr is... The examples in sources use udp for the broadcast so it will be very annoying  if i have to implement a transport layer.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You sound quite confused. Do you know how to send unicast packet and want to modify your code to send a broadcast packet, or you just want to send any packet? For RDC layer having broadcast vs. unicast packets may not make a large difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should check a bit the doc and the code, that could help you a lot.
`ptr` is a data pointer `(void*)`.  So its your data to send.
`mac_call_back_t` is clear : to trigger a callback to the mac layer. (a function pointer)
To send a broadcast, just send to FFF address. (you must change the address with packetbuf, check the doc of packetbuf. (a good link for packet_buf : http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Packetbuffer_Basics)
Check the `broadcast_conn` in Rime to understand how broadcast are done and to have an example.

Comment: `ptr` is definately not the data to send.

Comment: @kfx Then what his the purpose of ptr ? All my applications on contiki work with ptr as the data. Maybe I do wrong, but then tell me what the original purpose.

Comment: I grepped Contiki code for this. Looks like it's only used by Rime, to specify a channel: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/rime/rime.c#L183  The other sending code just passes `NULL` as the `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

RDC stands for "radio duty cycling". The RDC layer uses radio functions directly, so sending a packet could be as simple as calling `NETSTACK_RADIO.send(packetbuf_hdrptr(), packetbuf_totlen())`.

The Contiki network stack has this layering structure:

```
NETWORK layer -> MAC layer -> RDC layer -> RADIO layer.
```

(In recent versions there's an additional LLSEC layer between NETWORK and MAC layers.)

So an implementation of RDC layer API uses the RADIO layer API and is called by / reports to MAC layer API. You can look at `core/net/mac/nullrdc.c` to see how to implement a simple RDC driver.

As you noted, `NETSTACK_RDC.send(mac_callback_t sent, void *ptr)` takes two parameters. The first is of callback type which you need to call after finishing the sending, the second is user data you need to pass to the to the callback.

The callback is typedef in `net/mac/mac.h` as:

```
typedef void (* mac_callback_t)(void *ptr, int status, int transmissions);
```

- `ptr` is the user data pointer passed to `NETSTACK_RDC.send`;
- `status` is MAC status code, such as `MAC_TX_OK` - the result of the
  transmission;
- `transmissions` is the number of transmissions.